# how to get the value by the help of includes/index of

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to get the value in any way if key does match with "Item"

```
   const data = [{
            "Item-55566": "phone",        
        },
        {
            "Items-44555": "Case",       
        }
    ];
    
    /* How to get value if index found by Item */
    
    for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i].includes("Item"));
        //Expecting phone and case
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) allows you to loop through the keys in an object. Not to be confused with [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), which loop through elements in an array.

```js
const data = [{
          "Item-55566": "phone",        
      },
      {
          "Items-44555": "Case",       
      }
 ];
 
for(let datum of data)
{
  for(let key in datum)
  {
    if(key.includes("Item"))
    {
      console.log(datum[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we do like if it will not check case sensitive it can accept Item and item as well

Comment: @simon you can use `.toLowerCase()` before comparison. i.e. `key.toLowerCase().includes("item")`. "Item" will be converted to "item" and compare with "item".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your loop (good that it's only one loop compared to other answers) you can do it with Object.keys and values:

```js
   const data = [{
            "Item-55566": "phone",        
        },
        {
            "Items-44555": "Case",       
        }
    ];
    
    /* How to get value if index found by Item */
    
    for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
        if(Object.keys(data[i])[0].includes('Item')){
            console.log(Object.values(data[i])[0]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the simple way just change data[i].includes("Item") to data[i].keys().includes("Item").

BUT! Could we have some alternative data set here? For example:

```
const data = [{
        "Item-55566": "phone",
        "SomeKey: "Some Value",
        123123: "Numeric key with value"
    },
    {
        "Items-44555": "Case",
        "Another-key": "Another value"
    }
];
```

In this case you need to put some changes in your code to find correct keys & values:

```
for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    data[i].keys().forEach(v=>{ 
      String(v).includes("Item") && console.log("Got index: ${i}, key: ${v}, value: ${data[i][v]}") 
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter all items of the data array which includes `Item` text.

Then you can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to render new value from each object comes from `data array`.

```js
const data = [
{"Item-55566": "phone", }, 
{ "Items-44555": "Case",},
{ "Other-44555": "Nope",}];
var filteredItems = data.filter(item => Object.keys(item)[0].includes("Item"));  

console.log(filteredItems.map(item => Object.values(item)[0]));
```

**Refactor code - By using [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**

```js
const data = [
{"Item-55566": "phone", }, 
{ "Items-44555": "Case",},
{ "Other-44555": "Nope",}];

var res = data.reduce((prev, curr) => 
{
  var entries = Object.entries(curr)[0];
  if(entries[0].includes("Item"))
    prev.push(entries[1]);

  return prev;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: you actually dont need two loops (filter and map) here. this can be achvieved with one.

Comment: Yup, Refactor code - By using .reduce() @MWO

Answer (score 0):

The for loop iterates through the two objects, so you can check to see whether the object has that particular property using **hasOwnProperty()**

```
const data = [
```

{
"Item-55566": "phone",
},
{
"Items-44555": "Case",
},
];

/* How to get value if index found by Item */

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

```
if (data[i].hasOwnProperty("Item-55566")) {
console.log(data[i]);
```

}
}